# Is it possible you place text within another elements margin?

Tags: html, css

SO designing a website, I ran into a particular problem.

I want two columns of text next to each other. So I floated (left) the first set of text left, and set a margin of 50% to keep it to one side. But when I did the next column of text, and floated it right (I tried left too), but it appears under the former column of text. I also tried using position:relative and moving it, but it refused to move.

I am guessing this is becuase elements cannot be placed within another elements margin.

Please help, with no Javascript. It is evil.

html

```
<h1 id="firstcolumn">blahblahblahblahblahblah</h1>
<h2 id="secondthingy">foobarfoobarfoobar</h2>
```

css

```
#firstcolumn {
    float: left;
    margin: 20;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 50%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    font-size: 200%;
}
#secondthingy { 
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to place second div inside 1st div margin? make no sense to me. They can be place next to each other: http://jsfiddle.net/6LCtc/

Comment: JavaScript is not evil.  Without it, no AJAX.  Without AJAX, no more dynamic web... then we're back to 1999.  You'll probably have better luck if you set the width of each column and stop trying to put things inside a margin.

Comment: I'm sorry guys for my view on Javascript, and I'm sorry I'm so stupid, but was it really worth a -4. I'm sorry, if it makes anyone feel better. It's just that, me, myself, have javascript disabled at all time when making webpages, cause I know some people go with it off. I also don't use Javascript. And come on guys, it was a joke. :(

Comment: @wkoomson:  You are the first developer I've ever heard of that doesn't use JavaScript both as a coder and a surfer.  **You are clearly in the minority.**  Facebook is only one example of a site that's impossible to use without JavaScript.  With 700 million users, they must be doing something right.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry, I apologize, I didn't know. I guess I should probably learn/use it. Sorry for the ignorant comment. I was just sorta mad. :(

Comment: @Sparky672: He meant -4 as in -4 reputation (each downvote costs him 2).

Comment: @thirtydot:  Oh yes, of course.

Comment: @wkoomson:  Please say whatever you want about JavaScript, it won't hurt my feelings, I cuss at it myself every day.  But since it's impossible to create a dynamic website without JavaScript, I just thought I'd call you out on your comment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope I'm not like doing some thing wrong about asking another question, but where is a good site I can learn JS for free? Is w3schools good? That's where I learned HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you two columns of left aligned text:

```
#firstcolumn {
    float: left;
    margin: 20;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    font-size: 200%;
}

#secondthingy { 
float: right;
    text-align:left;
    width:45%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a `<div class="wrapper"></div>` and fix a width to it.

then put two `<div class="column"></div>` into that  that are `float: left` and have those two columns set to 50% of the wrapper.

then put your text into each of the columns.

I believe this is what you were attempting to do. if not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

`#secondthingy { 
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 2 extra margin values on #firstcolumn to get the desired result:

```
#firstcolumn {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: black;
  border-right-width: 3px;
  font-size: 200%;
}

#secondthingy { 
  float: right;
}
```

I think the margining was taking up too much space and causing the h2 to be pushed down a line.